# Global variable error when compiling in Xcode (C programming)

Tags: c, xcode, variables, global-variables

I am trying to understand "Global Variables", and I am running a program from a textbook:

It gives an Error in "Xcode Version 9.3 (9E145)" and the Error is:

**Redefinition of 'glob' as different kind of symbol**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void add(void);
void sub(void);

int glob = 10;

int main(void)
{
  add();
  printf("Val = %d\n", glob);
  sub();
  printf("Val = %d\n", glob);
  return 0;
}

void add(void)
{
  glob++;
}

void sub(void)
{
  glob--;
}
```

**I have a question:**

Why Xcode gives this error?

Comment: `I learned that void functions do not return any value.` Not returning anything doesn't mean it can't change global state.

Comment: Perhaps on a mac, stdio.h somehow brings the prototype for the glob(3) function.

Comment: Did you try to rename `glob` into e.g. `globalvariableofunusedname`? I have a superstition, that short identifier names are unlucky...

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, you are right. Apparently, it is reserved for something :) soo easy

Comment: I cannot read the screen shots.

Comment: @Yunnosch I can't thank you enough. Thank you for your remarks :) I added the error message too.

Comment: Also, the context of where/how it appears might be important. I am still not sure whether it is only an ambitious IDE or really the compiler. In this case I am actually in favor of having a screenshot with all those details. In addition to textual code and textual quote of error message. Feel free to add as much information on this as you can. It increases the chance for somebody actually explaining to the bottom.

Comment: Please double check your phrasing "When I try to run the program...". If I understood you correctly, it is either when compiling, or already while editing by the IDE. That makes the situation very different. Runtime errors are something very different.

Comment: I removed the phrasing, to avoid confusion. If you double checked that it is actually occuring when running the program (as opposed to when compiling or editing), please accept my apology.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170032/discussion-between-zulfidin-khodzhaev-and-yunnosch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not ask why. But one of your compilers (or maybe it is just something like an ambitious syntax-highlighter) quite clearly is convinced of having previously seen `glob` as the identifier for something else.
Searching, I did not find anything obvious and it surely is strange that in a short code with only the most widely used of includes, two compilers have different opinions.

But the immediate way to get around your problem should be to simply rename `glob`  to something different. Using a longer name, with a little more suggestion added, could not hurt. A slightly exaggerated proposal would be

```
int globalvariableofunusedname = 10;
```

This only answer your first question. For the second (if you keep it here), check the plausible comments. I recommend however to separate it into its own question post.

Comment: See [Darwin glob](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/glob.3.html) I am not sure the GCC in the OP's question is actually run on MacOS.

Comment: I did see a few `glob`s when searching, but seeming to need another include for being in scope... Mostly trying to get the problem solved. (And maybe to spread my superstition of too short identifers being evil, without advocating the hilariously long one I used in the answer.)

Comment: I am really aware now :) short variables are evil.

Comment: @Sulthan Interesting. Are you saying that "stdio.h" might contain a  `glob` on only some environments? Maybe OP can provide environment info and you can make a real "go-to-the-bottom" answer. I would be happy to upvote yours, even if it outshines my little "heal-the-symptoms" answer.